# Localized wrapping in vim

Tags: vim

I have wrapping turned on in vim, but is it possible to disable it for certain regions in the file I'm editing? To be specific, I'm editing LaTeX files, I would like the contents of some environments (tabular for example) not to be wrapped, since this would make the table contents much easier to read.

A solution based on automatically detecting such environments based on their opening/closing tags would be the best of course, but I'm not against a solution needing some explicit tags or commands in a comment in the file.

Comment: If you can't find any other solution, map `:set wrap` and `:set nowrap` to alt F-keys so you can quickly toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify the table regions through a particular syntax group, my [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) can help.

Alternatively, you can transparently edit the table parts in a separate buffer with the [NrrwRgn - A Narrow Region Plugin similar to Emacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) plugin.

Or, as the `'wrap'` option is window-local, just open a `:split` window of the same buffer with an inverted option value there.